# Initialize module after APP_INITIALIZE

Tags: angular

In my Angular 6 app I'm loading my externalized configuration via a Http Service like this:

```
export function getSettings(appLoadService: ConfigLoadService) {
  return () => appLoadService.getSettings();
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    ConfigLoadService,
    {provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: getSettings, deps: [ConfigLoadService], multi: true}]
})
export class AppLoadModule {
}
```

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigLoadService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getSettings(): Subscription {
    console.log("Loading config from server...");
    return this.http
      .get("/config.json")
      .subscribe((config: any) => {

        AppSettings.API_BASE_URL = config.API_BASE_URL;

        console.log("API_BASE_URL: " + AppSettings.API_BASE_URL);
      });
  }
}
```

Now I want to add an external dependency which needs to be initialized with the configuration present:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:
    DepModule.forRoot({
      apiBaseUrl: AppSettings.API_BASE_URL
    }),
  ],[...]
```

The problem here is that the dependency is imported and initialized before the `APP_INITIALIZER` and is therefore not properly configured. What am I missing here?

Comment: are you using a custom error handler?

Comment: @Nico no, I don't.

Comment: seems like your ConfigService depends on HttpClient which is missing from your appLoadModule

Comment: Yes, but that's not the problem. I shortened the code a little bit to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score -1):

The `APP_INITIALIZER` provider factory method must return a promise

So you would do something like:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigLoadService {

  private myConfig;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  getSettings() {
    return this.http.get('/config.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
        this.myConfig = data;
      });
  }

  getConfig() {
    return this.myConfig;
  }
}
```

Juri did a blog about it you can read more [App Runtime Config](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/)

Comment: Ok now I see that the property is properly printed out to the console but right after that `ERROR DOMException: "An invalid or illegal string was specified"` is thrown

Comment: which property?

Comment: AppSettings.API_BASE_URL is properly loaded via ConfigLoadService, then printed on the console and then the exception is thrown.

Comment: Then that error must be coming from your DepModule? You can also create an InjectionToken based on the config and just use that inside of your DepModule

Comment: I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4g9ay). The error I get on the console is different from the error I get local. The issue seems to be in the constructor in app.component.ts.

Comment: Yes that seems to be a problem outside of your original problem.
Please mark if it has helped.

Comment: This is because you are passing `MQTT_HOST` that is not initialized yet by your config service to your module. Please update this if you found a solution to this @user6845507

Comment: @user6845507 Assume you took a different route as explained on this [MQTT github issue](https://github.com/sclausen/ngx-mqtt/issues/23)